# Git - Ignore node_modules folder everywhere

Tags: git, node-modules

I have a project containing multiple other projects :

- Main project

  - Mini project 1
  - Mini project 2

All containing `node_modules` folder. I want git to ignore the folder no matter where it is starting from the root folder. Something like this to add in .gitignore :

```
*node_modules/*
```

Answer (score 1309, accepted):

Add  `node_modules/`
or `node_modules`
to the `.gitignore` file to ignore all directories called `node_modules` in the current folder and any subfolders like the below image.

[image: example]

Comment: what would be the glob path to do the same for karma, excludes?

Comment: For a gitignore template for nodejs: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Node.gitignore

Comment: See @AndrewSchreiber's answer if you have previously added the node_modules folder to git. You'll need to remove it from the cache with "git rm -r --cached node_modules".

Comment: After enabling this, 10000+ file commits saved which was just not letting me do anything with git :D

Comment: You don't need the slash at the end

Comment: The question needs an answer. Choose one before community does.

Answer (score 309):

Use the **universal one-liner** in terminal in the project directory:

> touch .gitignore && echo "node_modules/" >> .gitignore && git rm -r --cached node_modules ; git status

It works no matter if you've created a `.gitignore` or not, no matter if you've added `node_modules` to git tracking or not.

Then commit and push the `.gitignore` changes.

**Explanation**

`touch` will generate the `.gitignore` file if it doesn't already exist.

`echo` and `>>` will append `node_modules/` at the end of `.gitignore`, causing the `node_modules` folder and all subfolders to be ignored.

`git rm -r --cached` removes the `node_modules` folder from git control if it was added before. Otherwise, this will show a warning `pathspec 'node_modules' did not match any files`, which has no side effects and you can safely ignore. The flags cause the removal to be recursive and include the cache.

`git status` displays the new changes. A change to `.gitignore` will appear, while `node_modules` will not appear as it is no longer being tracked by git.

Comment: `touch` shouldn't be necessary here: `>>` will create the file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: `touch` is needed. `>>` will return `no such file or directory: .gitignore` otherwise.

Comment: Hmm, seems to differ from OS to OS

Comment: `echo "node_modules/" > .gitignore` should create a _new_ file with original content, using `>>` _appends_ text onto the end of existing specified file

Comment: you need to remove th " " around the node_modules in windows cmd

Comment: @AndrewSchreiber   should we have to apply this command in the main project folder or mini-project folder

Comment: I think `git rm -r` is to remove from both INDEX and working directory. And then `git rm -r --cached` is to remove from INDEX but keep it in working directory

Answer (score 126):

### Edit - (After 2022-04-09)

In a new monorepo setup I found just using this

```
node_modules
```

solved it to ignore all the node_modules in the subdirectory, note there is no slash before or after which means recursive.

[Reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format)

### Old Way - (Before 2022-04-09)

```
**/node_modules
```

`**` is used for a recursive call in the whole project

> Two consecutive asterisks `**` in patterns matched against full pathname may have special meaning:
>
> A leading `**` followed by a slash means match in all directories. For example, `**/foo` matches file or directory `foo` anywhere, the same as pattern `foo`. `**/foo/bar` matches file or directory `bar` anywhere that is directly under directory `foo`.
>
> A trailing `/**` matches everything inside. For example, `abc/**` matches all files inside directory `abc`, relative to the location of the .gitignore file, with infinite depth.
>
> A slash followed by two consecutive asterisks then a slash matches zero or more directories. For example, `a/\**/b` matches `a/b`, `a/x/b`, `a/x/y/b` and so on.
>
> Other consecutive asterisks are considered invalid.

### Why this approach is better than `node_modules/`

The `**` acts as a recursive pattern. It is useful in monorepo projects where you have node_modules in sub directories. `**` will search for all the node_modules inside the directory & ignore them.

[Reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: Care to explain why this approach is better than simply `node_modules/`?

Comment: In case of a monorepo, you could have several frontends to deal with. This approach will recursively ignore all the `node_modules` folders, independently of where they are located (e.g. `/BackOffice/frontend/node_modules`)

Comment: You don't need the `**`, it works the same without it

Comment: That didn't work for me, that is the reason I created this answer. For react native monorepo & firebase with cloud functions.

Comment: This is wild. 'wanna go for a walk?'' Blow them out of existence. That'l fix it.Put a disclaimer on your 'code'.

Answer (score 33):

First and foremost thing is to add `.gitignore` file in my-app. Like so in image below.

[image: Put .gitignore in the parent folder/directory of node_modules.]

and next add this in your `.gitignore` file

```
/node_modules
```

## Note

You can also add others files too to ignore them to be pushed on github. Here are some more files kept in .gitignore. You can add them according to your requirement. `#` is just a way to comment in .gitignore file.

```sh
# See https://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# dependencies
/node_modules

# testing
/coverage

# production
/build

# misc
.DS_Store
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local

npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
```

Comment: Why would you add build to the .gitignore?

Comment: @SebastianNielsen The same reason we don't track node_modules.  You get build/ by compiling.

Comment: Do not add the slash at the start, it stops this from being recursive

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer can you create UR

Comment: @MustkeemK - sorry, what is UR?

Answer (score 14):

Adding below line in .gitignore will ignore node modules from the entire repository.

```
node_modules
```

[image]

Comment: This is recursive

Answer (score 7):

Create **.gitignore** file in root folder directly by code editor or by command

For Mac & Linux

```
 touch .gitignore
```

For Windows

```
 echo >.gitignore
```

open **.gitignore** declare folder or file name like this **/foldername**

Comment: I guess you meant `echo >.gitignore`. ;)

Answer (score 6):

```
**node_modules
```

This works for me

recursive approach to ignore all node_modules present in sub folders

Answer (score 4):

**it will automatically create a `.gitignore` file if  not then create a file name `.gitignore`**
and add copy & paste the below code

```
# dependencies
/node_modules
/.pnp
.pnp.js

# testing
/coverage

# production
/build

# misc
.DS_Store
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local

npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
```

these below are all unnecessary files

**See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ for more about ignoring files.**

and save the `.gitignore` file and you can upload

Answer (score 4):

If you wanna do it via the command line, type in `echo node_modules/ > .gitignore`. You can check if git is tracking the folder by typing in `git status`. If its being tracked type in `git rm -r --cached node_modules`.

Answer (score 2):

Add below line to your .gitignore

`/node_modules/`

In my case, writing /node_modules without the foreslash after was not working

Answer (score 1):

If your subproject/client node_modules gets committed,

```
    # dependencies
    /node_modules
    /.pnp
    .pnp.js

    # testing
    /coverage

    # production
    /build

    # misc
    .DS_Store
    .env.local
    .env.development.local
    .env.test.local
    .env.production.local

    npm-debug.log*
    yarn-debug.log*
    yarn-error.log*
```

then add "node_modules" at the last line.

```
    # dependencies
    /node_modules
    /.pnp
    .pnp.js

    # testing
    /coverage

    # production
    /build

    # misc
    .DS_Store
    .env.local
    .env.development.local
    .env.test.local
    .env.production.local

    npm-debug.log*
    yarn-debug.log*
    yarn-error.log*
    node_modules 
    # ------ Up Here ------
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Sourcetree app in Mac or Windows

1. Open sourcetree
2. click particular project
3. click settings
4. click Advanced
5. click  Edit gitignore
6. Write "node_modules"
7. And Save.

For more information about this free Git client visit
https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with SVN/Tortoise git as well.

just right click on node_modules -> Tortoise git -> add to ignore list.

This will generate .gitIgnore for you and you won't find node_modules folder in staging again.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps -

- open git bash on the folder where your project is, or open vs code terminal
  by hitting

```
CTRL + `
```

- write, [ echo > .gitignore ] in the terminal or, create a file [.gitignore] directly into the folder
- then write this to ignore node modules from entire repository

```
node_modules
```

- or, try this to ignore all node_modules from multiple sub folders

```
**node_modules
```

**Note :** if you make spelling mistake while typing the name of the folder or file, it won't work. so, double check spelling

Answer (score 0):

Add node_modules/ or node_modules to the .gitignore file to ignore all directories called node_modules in the current folder and any subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows 8/10/11/12**

```
- echo "node_modules/" >> .gitignore (create gitignore file)
- git rm -r --cached node_modules (remove node module if add)
- git status
```

Answer (score -2):

Add below line to your .gitignore

```
*/node_modules/*
```

This will ignore all node_modules in your current directory as well as subdirectory.

Comment: Note that there is already an accepted answer to this question. Please [edit] your answer to ensure that it improves upon other answers already present in this question.

Answer (score -2):

foe the ones who are trying the answers above and still facing the problem

I've tried almost all of the answers eventually , it fixed my problem with ignoring node_modules but only after i committed the changes !

Answer (score -3):

just add different .gitignore files to mini project 1 and mini project 2. Each of the .gitignore files should /node_modules and you're good to go.

Comment: I think this is what the original poster wanted to avoid.  The question asked how to make a single .gitignore change to exclude all node_modules folders.

Comment: oh...he wasn't specific about having just 1 .gitignore file