# git add . command no response when adding node_modules

Tags: node.js, git, webpack

I have run

```
git init
npm install --save-dev webpack
```

Then, there is a package.json and a node_modules directory in the root directory.
I want to add the node_modules directory into git repo.
After I run

```
git add .
```

There is no response any more. And I found the git.exe process occupy more and more memory usage , but there is not any response after several hours.
What is wrong with it? 
Is it caused by pretty much files to be added into repo by git?
How can I debug what happens in detail when that command is executed?
Everything works fine if I just `git add` some other files/folder which is not node_modules.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you `git init` the repo folder? If yes, then you can run `git status`. There you should see any new or changed folder.

If `node_modules` is not mentioned, I guess you have a `.gitignore` file in your project folder. If you want to `git add` the node modules folder you will need to remove `node_modules/` from `.gitignore`.

`npm install --save-dev webpack` will just add one more dependency in package.json and install webpack in your node local repo. This is not a git related command.

Check also this question: [Git - Ignore node_modules folder everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820791/git-ignore-node-modules-folder-everywhere)

Hopfully this will help,

Comment: Yes, i have done git init. And everything ok if i not add the node_modules directory which created by the 'npm install --save-dev webpack' command.

Comment: Ok, do you have a `.gitignore` file ?

Comment: No, i do not have a .gitignore file

Comment: Can you please send a print screen from your repo folder (after you have run the `npm install --save-dev webpack` cmd on files/folder structure `ls -la` and `git status` ?

Comment: Please see the screen i pasted here.

Comment: can you try `git reset` and then `git add .` ?

Comment: thanks, i have done this , no lucky. I wonder whether or not it is webpack issue. My os is windows 10

Answer (score 1):

I figured out myself. 
This is caused by pretty much symlinks in the node_modules directory. If i evaluated the git-bash as administrator, the new installed node_module symlinks can be created as linux. And then when git add works well. Maybe, if without evaluated git-bash, git-bash can not create symlinks which cause pretty much files need to be git added, even worse maybe a circular reference between symblink and node module staff (not sure), that cause memory consumption of git increase always and no response.
Hope it can help others if met the same problem on windows.