# Ignoring a folder to commit in git

Tags: git

I have an application which I am making

The App as usual have two parts

```
-> The frontend 
-> The Backend
```

Both frontend and Backend are inside parent a folder which I initialised using git init.

```
ParentFolder 
--> Frontend 
--> Backend
// Git Initialisation is done on Parent folder
```

Now whenever I add module for frontend and backend and do git add, git commit, it is also committing the node module inside the frontend and backend.

**[Question:]** So i want git to ignore node modules folder in frontend and backend, So how can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git - Ignore node\_modules folder everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820791/git-ignore-node-modules-folder-everywhere)

Comment: Please add folder structure with node_modules mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `.gitignore` file at the root of your project and target any **node_modules** folder.

[.gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

> A gitignore file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git should ignore. Files already tracked by Git are not affected

---

**Structure**

```
Parent folder
   Frontend   (folder)
   Backend    (folder)
  .git        (folder)
  .gitignore  (file)
```

**.gitignore** file content

```
node_modules/
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `.gitignore` file will help you do this.

Considering you have the following structure:

```
->ParentFolder 
|-->Frontend 
|     |-->node modules
|
|---> Backend
|     |-->node modules
```

You can use the following lines in the `.gitignore` file created at the root of your project.

```
*/node_modules/
```