# Stop VS Code from traking changes to node_modules

Tags: node.js, git, visual-studio-code, node-modules

I am working on a git branch and I'm using VS Code to track any changes I make to the branch.

However, when I ran `npm install`, VS Code started to track node_modules which has 850+ changes.

I've added it to `.gitignore` file but there is no change so far.

[image]

Comment: where did you put your .gitignore file?

Comment: It's in the root folder.

Comment: Node modules has been committed. They need to be removed and then ignored.

Comment: you will drag on this committed stuff in the repository. Start a new repository and setup correct and copy over the old source files and do an initial commit. Check each file before putting to the stage to see if `.gitignore` is configured correct. Do not commit anything that is generated

Comment: @evolutionxbox thank you. Someone at work told me the same thing and it was actually the problem.

Comment: @rioV8 thank you. That's the exact procedure I followed and now node_modules/ are being ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make sure your .gitignore file is in the same parent directory as the node_modules folder.

```
project_directory
  - .gitignore
  - node_modules
  - other files
```

you might also checkout: [Git - Ignore node_modules folder everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820791/git-ignore-node-modules-folder-everywhere)

Comment: I'll try this out; I've accidentally commited and there's no changes to be tracked.

Comment: oh yep! once you commit a file it becomes tracked by git no matter what... so as the others have mentioned in the comments on your question, you have to remove the file(s) and then ignore them for it to stick.

Comment: Exactly! Thank was actually what the issue was. Thank you for your answer as well. I moved the file from the root folder and now it is working.