# My full stack application files are not uploading to GitHub, git add is hanging?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, node-modules, mern

I have created a full-stack web application using Mern stack, but when I now try to upload the file to GitHub the terminal is hanging. And in VsCode it is showing 9k+ file changes in the source control panel, below I have attached all the images

[image: ProjBackend is here]

projfront end is attached below

[image: Projfrontend file is here]

I have created a git repository in the main file, I have deleted the `.git` file in the front end of my application(As while using react it will be automatically created), there is only one `.git` in the main file.

I am not able to add anything, the command  `git add .`

[image]

the terminal will hang when I use it, the terminal won't respond. Can anyone help here? How to upload these files to GitHub and clarify what is happening, why it is coming like this.

After entering git status
[image]

Comment: Did you skipped node_modules to be published to Github ?

Comment: @RebaiAhmed Noo

Comment: Just check these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820791/git-ignore-node-modules-folder-everywhere, try to skip node-modules and try again to make git add

Comment: @RebaiAhmed the error remains the same

Comment: do you have a `.git` folder in a parent folder, use `git status` to see which files are (un)tracked, get a list of all the 9K files, or view the scm bar

Comment: Can you tried to install Gitbash ? instead of using vscode terminal

Comment: @rioV8 i have ```.git``` in parent folder, and i saw all 9k files, but those are all the changes made for whole project, but I was adding day by day, so it can't be 9k by now

Comment: @RebaiAhmed Yes, the problem remains same, when I use git add, it is hanging

Comment: With that many files, it's clear you need a `.gitignore` to tell Git to ignore those generated files and folders that are not part of your source code. `git status` should tell you what they are, but you'll have to be patient when you run it, since it might have to scan all 9K+ files for you and display their status. `git add .` is certainly a bad idea at this point: you don't want to commit all that stuff!

Comment: @joanis I have uploaded the image which shows the status, when I give ```git status```, please have a look into it

Comment: where are all the 9K files, they are not shown in your status image (what is wrong with copy paste text), or are these files in `projbackend`

Comment: It looks like your entire `projfrontend` and `projbackend` are not in Git yet. How many files are in those folders? (e.g., `find projfrontend | wc` and `find profbackend | wc` will tell you). Do you really mean to add *all* the files in those two folders to your Git repo? `git add .` will recursively scan and add everything it finds that is not excluded by your `.gitignore`.

Comment: In one of my node projects, I just did `find node_modules | wc` and it told me I have 22081 files in there. In that case, adding `node_modules` to my `.gitignore` would be essential, as you were asked in the very first comment in this thread. When you said "same error", I might guess you didn't do it correctly, or else it's up to you to find out the name of the folder with thousands of files in it in your project.

Comment: @joanis yeah correct, it has been solved now, the ```.gitignore``` was not ignoring node_modules, so I added again clearly "node_modules" to ```.gitignore``` now it is solved

Comment: Glad yo know it's solved now. This is a very common situation, for every project you have to make sure you have a suitable `.gitignore` associated with it.

Comment: Note that even a hundred thousand files should take at most a few minutes to `git add`. (At, e.g., a mere 10 files per second, 100_000 files is 10_000 seconds or under 3 hours, and at the more reasonable 1000 files per second it's 100 seconds or under 2 minutes. ) Of course you almost certainly don't want to bother with all the generated files.

Answer (score 1):

By adding
`touch .gitignore && echo "node_modules/" >> .gitignore && git rm -r --cached node_modules`

in all the subfolders and in the main project folder, this problem has been solved.